# How to write/read 8 true/false in a single byte on rust language

Tags: memory-management, rust, byte, bit

Everyone knows that bool uses 1 byte and not 1 bite.

In case I want to store 8 (or more) true/false in a single byte,
how can I do it on Rust?

Something like this:

```
fn main()
{
   let x:ByteOnBits;
   x[3]=true;
   if x[4]
   {
      println!("4th bit is true");
   }
}
```

an array of 8 bools would be 8 bytes, not 1 byte as I am expecting.

Comment: Bools aren't 1 bit, while they do (basically) represent either a 1 or a 0, so it technically only takes 1 bit to store it, almost every language stores it as an entire byte. There isn't any noticeable memory savings or performance improvements by making it so. Check out [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6abff46b6a2e9ad527328e99a2559d88) Rust playground showing how large a bool is (1, byte)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`bitvec` crate](https://crates.io/crates/bitvec) provides facilities of the kind you're asking for:

```
use bitvec::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut data = 0u8;
    let bits = data.view_bits_mut::<Lsb0>();
    bits.set(3, true);
    if bits[4] {
        println!("xxx");
    }
    assert_eq!(data, 8);
}
```

Comment: does bitvec only uses 1 byte?

Comment: @WORMHACKER `bitvec` can convert many different data types into a bit vector - including a `u8` (byte, shown here), `u16`, arrays of various sizes, etc. Consult its documentation for details.

Comment: but i have to create an int type its... bruh

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`bitflags`](https://docs.rs/bitflags/latest/bitflags/) crate to use bits as bools stored in different sizes. Although it is intended for other uses, you can still leverage its functionality for it.